# HTTP_USER_AGENT showing "proximic; +http://www.proximic.com/info/spider.php"

Tags: php, http, firefox, browser, user-agent

I have a website set up on the internet.
Using PHP, I am reading the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

When I am accessing the website from my Firefox browser, instead of showing the actual details, it is showing the following:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; proximic; +http://www.proximic.com/info/spider.php)
```

However, it shows the correct value when I am using a `Private Window`.

What is this http://www.proximic.com/info/spider.php agent?

What can be the possible security hole that I have created within my browser?

Comment: Look in your add-ons -> extensions and disable them all, turn them on one by one to see which one is causing this issue.

Comment: @cmorrissey: I will do so. But what is this `http://www.proximic.com/info/spider.php` agent?

Comment: @cmorrissey: After disabling all the addons, it showed correct agent, i.e. `proximic` issue was gone. But after enabling all the addons again, it is still showing correct agent and not the `proximic` one. Strange!